# how to use gcc -M for autodependency generator

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, dependencies

I got a advice on code review to use `-M` options family with `gcc` to generate auto dependency generation
the problem is that the documentation is confusing me and I still dont understand how am I supposed to use it when I simply added -M to CFLAGS
the and still I could barely find any difference I just got the
`warning: main.o: linker input file unused because linking not done`
I am using `gcc 4.8.4`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not enough to change how you invoke the compiler -- you also have to change your Makefile to make use of the newly-generated information.

Paul Smith wrote a [good guide to how to set up automatic dependency tracking](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/) for make.

Answer (score 2):

For a fully automatic version that doesn't interfere with "clean" targets, use something like this:

```
%.d: %.c Makefile
    $(CC) -MM -MT"$@ $(@:.d=.o)" -MF$@ $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) $<

ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),clean)
ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),distclean)
-include $(OBJS:.o=.d)
endif
endif
```

This assumes you have a list of object files to be linked in `$(OBJS)`. The `-MT` parameter here makes sure that the dependency file itself will have the same dependencies as the object file. Without it, the generated dependency file would e.g. look like

```
foo.o: foo.c foo.h bar.h
```

but you want

```
foo.o foo.d: foo.c foo.h bar.h
```

so dependencies are also recreated when you change source.

This scheme of doing it doesn't change your rule to create the object files, dependencies are generated in an extra compiler invocation. There are also alternatives doing both code and dependency generation in a single run. The above is what I like to use.

Comment: If I just knew how to make a local chat. Sometimes there appears an appropriate message with a link, but I still did not get when or how to make it on my own. One day I really should read the FAQ.